# eChart... How do I refine the polar graph?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I need to implement this picture .

**GOAL**

[image]

**CURRENT, MINE**

[image]

I'm done like this, but I have no idea to complete, gpt said wrong answer.

As shown above, How can I

1. paint the edges with the background color(yellow green) as well,
2. give an empty space between the axis Tick of the circle inside and the circle,
3. make the two Series (pies) overlap like in the picture above (they are overlapping, but in my implementation, the pies are not overlapping)
4. how do I get rid of the center circle? I asked GPT, but he didn't give me an answer. lol

here is my current code.

```js
 var chartDom = document.getElementById('my_stat_chart');
 var total_stat_graph = echarts.init(chartDom, null, { renderer: 'svg'});

total_stat_option = {

  border:"1px solid green",
  padding:"10px",
  angleAxis: {
    show: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    clockwise: false,
    startAngle:270,
    axisLine: {
        lineStyle: {
            color: '#7EE9AD', // Set the color of the angleAxis
        }
    },
    axisTick: {
        show: false, // Hide axis tick marks
    },
    axisLabel:{
        show:false
    }
  },
  radiusAxis: {
    show: false,
    type: "category",
    data: ["Standard"],
    z:10,
  },
  polar: {
    radius: ["75%", "50%"], /* size of inner Circle */
    center: ["50%", "50%"],
    backgroundStyle: {
      color: "#c6f7d1",
    },
  },
  series: [
    {
      animation:true,
      type: "bar",
      coordinateSystem: "polar",
      data: [36.2],
      color: "#4cbc7c",
      barWidth: 15,
      showBackground: true,
      backgroundStyle: {
        color: "#c6f7d1",
      },
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0]
      },
      barGap:0
    },
    {
      animation:true,
      type: "bar",
      coordinateSystem: "polar",
      data: [50],
      color:"#ffe36e",
      barWidth: 8,
      barGap:0,
      showBackground: true,
      backgroundStyle: {
        color: "#c6f7d1",
      },
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0] /* BAR STYLE*/
      }
    },
  ]
};

my_stat_option&&my_stat_graph.setOption(my_stat_option);
```